# Why does a PDF become corrupt/unreadable after mailing it through SMTP with Email::MIME?

Tags: perl, email, smtp, mime, multipart

I have followed the examples in [Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aSender) and [Email::MIME](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aMIME) and it looks good, until you try to open the PDF. Then it is clear that it is smaller in size than the original and somehow corrupt. My script is more or less a template copy of the examples given for testing purposes, but I fear that the MIME stuff does not really work here.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use IO::All ;

use Email::Simple;
use Email::Simple::Creator;

use Email::MIME;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP;

# assemble the parts
my @parts = (
    Email::MIME->create(
        attributes => {
            filename     => "report.pdf",
            content_type => "application/pdf",
            encoding     => "quoted-printable",
            name         => "report.pdf",
        },
        body => io("report.pdf")->all
    ),
    Email::MIME->create(
        attributes => {
            content_type => "text/plain",
            disposition  => "attachment",
            charset      => "US-ASCII",
        },
        body => "Hello there!",
    ),
);

# assemble parts into email
my $email = Email::MIME->create(
    header => [
        To      => 'me@you.com',
        From    => 'me@you..com',
        Subject => "Thanks for all the fish ...",
    ],
    parts => [@parts],
);

# standard modifications
$email->header_set( 'X-PoweredBy' => 'RT v3.0' );

# more advanced
# $_->encoding_set('base64') for $email->parts;

# send the email
my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
    host => 'mail.whatever.com',
    # port => 2525,
    sasl_username => 'webuser',
    sasl_password => 's3cr3t',
    timeout       => 20,
});
sendmail( $email, { transport => $transport } );
```

I am using Windows and Perl 5.12.1.0. It does not seem to be the [IO::All](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aAll) module, but I think the issue is somewhere here. Does anyone know enough about this stuff to help me fix it?

I have tried binary mode, different SMTP servers, different PDF files, and I cannot get the damn thing to work at all.

Comment: Why did you comment out `encoding_set`?

Comment: beccause with or without it, it did not make any difference...

Comment: Have you tried dumping the message with `print $email->as_string;`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to encode your binary attachments before sending the email.

```
$_->encoding_set( 'base64' ) for $email->parts;
```

I don't know Email::MIME. I use [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME%3a%3aLite) and never had any problem because encoding is done automatically.

```
### Start with a simple text message:
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
     From    =>'me@myhost.com',
     To      =>'you@yourhost.com',
     Cc      =>'some@other.com, some@more.com',
     Subject =>'A message with 2 parts...',
     Type    =>'TEXT',
     Data    =>"Here's the GIF file you wanted"
);

### Attach a part... the make the message a multipart automatically:
$msg->attach(Type     =>'image/gif',
     Path     =>'aaa000123.gif',
     Filename =>'logo.gif'
);

MIME::Lite->send('smtp', "smtp.myisp.net", AuthUser=>"YourName", AuthPass=>"YourPass");
$msg->send;
```

Comment: Thank-you for reply PacoRG - I can see where you are going - but you do not get an $email object until you have made the call and passed the array of email parts - Completely confusing all this...

Comment: btw - I just tried the [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME%3a%3aLite) example and it works :-) :-( - the project requires me to use Email::Simple - apparently because it needs to work with gmail, and I believe that MIME::Lite cannot handle it.

Comment: I edited my answer. I meant before sending the email, before `Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new`, sorry for confusing you.

Comment: ok well thanks for that - put it back in but still does not work - I get an empty PDF doc - the MIME::Lite version you mentioned worked, but will not work with gmail...ARghhh! Just cannot seem to get any joy here..